# How do I determine the width of the result of codePointAt?

Tags: javascript, unicode, utf-16

I'm trying to loop over the Unicode characters in a Javascript string, that I assume is encoded with UTF-16.

It is my understanding that UTF-16 is *variable width*. That is, a single Unicode character may be split across multiple 16-bit characters. I can use `s[i].codePointAt` to get the Unicode character beginning at a given code point. But once I have it, how do I know how far to advance i?

Roughly, what is `getWidth` here? Is it simply `c > Math.pow(2, 16)`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length;) {
    var c = s.codePointAt(i);
    // do some operation with c
    i = i + getWidth(c)
}
```

Is there a standard library function I can use to determine how far to advance? Or a way to iterate over the Unicode code points in a string?

Comment: Are you talking about the font width ?

Comment: No. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16. Code points may be encoded as one or two UTF-16 units.

Comment: Right, my bad. I had to use `codePointAt` in one of my projects, so to get teh length I iterated using something like `for (var i = 0; myString.codePointAt(i); i++) { // Code here }`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a standard […] way to iterate over the Unicode code points in a string?

Yes, since ES6 you can simply [iterate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) all strings to get the code points:

```
for (const character of string) {
    const codepoint = character.codePointAt(0);
    // do some operation with codepoint
}
```

Comment: But remember that code points are not characters (graphemes). Unicode is more like a programming language (like PostScript) than a simple encoding. There are remarkable code points that have no representation in glyphs; they are simply instructions to the agent that renders the image as to what character to show, or where to show it. A single grapheme may contain dozens of code points.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    var c = s.codePointAt(i);
    // do some operation with c
    if( s.charCodeAt(i) != c) {
       ++i; // step past the next sixteen bits of the surrogate pair 
    }
}
```

(where the value of `c` is the Unicode codepoint, not the character).

If you want to split the string into an array of Unicode characters you can make use of the string iterator invoked by the spread operator introduced in ES6:

```
var array = [...s];
```

In pre-ES6 browsers the start of a surrogate pair can be identified in order to skip the second part:

```
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; ++i) {
    var k = s.charCodeAt(i);
    if( k < 0xD800 || k > 0xDBFF) {
        var c = s[i]; // character in BMP
    }
    else {
        c = s.substring( i,i+2); // use surrogate pair
        ++i;
    }
    // do something with c
    console.log(c)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See: http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#supplementary_code_point

Basically, if your code point is 0x010000+ you are dealing with multibyte character.

```
const MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT = 0x010000;
function charCount(int codePoint) {
    return codePoint >= MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT ? 2 : 1;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript predates Unicode and uses another, older system called [UCS2](http://hackipedia.org/Character%20sets/Unicode,%20UTF%20and%20UCS%20encodings/UCS-2.htm), which is very similar but doesn't handle surrogate pairs nor does it understand any characters that can't be represented by two bytes.

If you are stepping through a string looking at codepoints, you can look at the codepoint *value* itself... if the value is greater than 2<sup>^16</sup>, you have to advance 2 string characters, otherwise advance 1 string character.

You might try a new ES6 sytax that works really well at splitting up strings into characters, even if those characters are high-order.

```js
// High order unicode character
const k = '';

// Takes four bytes
console.log(k.length);

const chars = [...k];

// But its only one character
console.log(chars.length);
```